# https Request in Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, https, alexa-skills-kit

I can't seem to get HTTP requests to work in my alexa skill, here is the relevant sample code:

```
var https = require('https');

...

function getTreeFact(callbackFunction){


  var url = 'https://alexa.phl.chs.network/treefacts/index.php';

  https.get(url, function(res){
      var body = '';

      res.on('data', function(chunk){
          body += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function(){
          var gameResponse = JSON.parse(body);
          callbackFunction(gameResponse);
      });
  }).on('error', function(e){
    // Handle error
  });
}

...

this.getTreeFact(function (responseMessage){
    this.emit(':tell', responseMessage.message);
});
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I think I am making the HTTP request correctly. I know the skill works without this (simply commenting out the last three lines and replacing with just this.emit(':tell', 'hello') works fine).

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain my below code...Here I have used https request in the "LaunchRequest"
which in turns gives me a response and with that response and I'm making my alexa to speak

*note: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com is very useful for testing your https req and response*

Simply use this code in your aws online editor console make sure you type the right intent name and invocation name.

```
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        var speechResult;
    switch (event.request.type) {

         case "LaunchRequest":
             var resultis;
             const querystring = require('querystring');                                                                                                                                                                                                
             const https = require('https');


            var postData = querystring.stringify({
                    'msg' : 'Hello World!'
            });

     var options = {
        hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
        path: '/posts',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': postData.length
     }
 };

      var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
       //console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
      //console.log('headers:', res.headers);

     res.on('data', (d) => {
         //console.log("my data is "+d);
         var obj = JSON.parse(d);
         var resul = obj.msg;
         resultis = JSON.stringify(resul);
         context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse(resultis, true)));
     });
 });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
    });
     req.write(postData);
        req.end();
     break;
     case "IntentRequest":
          switch (event.request.intent.name) {
        case "MyIntent":
             var a = "are you ready";
             context.succeed(generateResponse(buildSpeechletResponse(a, true)))
             break;
           }
      break;
     }
  }
       //Alexa Speech function

      buildSpeechletResponse = (outputText, shouldEndSession) => {
            return {
              outputSpeech: {
                 type: "PlainText",
                 text: outputText
              },
              shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
          }
    }
        generateResponse = (speechletResponse) => {
              return {
                  version: "1.0",
                  response: speechletResponse
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's official github page has a very thorough documentation on api calls. Check their Cooking list skill documentation it covers all of the get and post requests https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook

and https://github.com/alexa/ main repo for other samples.

Comment: I attempted to use the code they have, but it still gives me the same error. I thought it was the site I'm accessing but simply using google.com isn't working either...
I just wish it would actually display the error message

Comment: I tried accessing the website in your code on my browser but it seems it is down, trying google.com won't work as it doesnt spit out JSON. Try testing with [this link](http://ip.jsontest.com)

Answer (score 0):

You better use a promise version, for example

https://github.com/request/request-promise

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like

```
this.emit(':tell', responseMessage.message);
```

should be

```
this.emit(':tell', responseMessage);
```

I can't see any `.message` in this

```
var gameResponse = JSON.parse(body);

callbackFunction(gameResponse);
```